# How to find factory reset happened on device

Tags: android-management-api

I need to find the applied policy status on device.
How to find if registered device on my group done factory reset, using Android Management API.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it via the Key : "DeviceState" in the GET API response of a device which indicates the states that may be applied to a device. [GET Device](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get)

If the `STATE is DELETED` then it means the device is no longer enrolled. This state will never be returned by an API call, but is used in the final status report published to Cloud Pub/Sub when the device acknowledges the deletion. [DeviceStates](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#devicestate)